# stop progress dialog when get the whole data

Tags: android, load, backendless

It might be a simple problem but I have wasted hours before it That I wants that after loading the data from Backendless different time when the whole list will be loaded then the progress dialog cant be accessed by "need to load more" function.

here's my code

```
    adapter = new MainAdapter( MainActivity.this, R.layout.main_row_item, totalMains );

    setListAdapter( adapter );

    QueryOptions queryOptions = new QueryOptions();
    queryOptions.setRelated( Arrays.asList( "message" ) );

    BackendlessDataQuery query = new BackendlessDataQuery( queryOptions );

    Backendless.Data.of( Main.class ).find( query, new LoadingCallBack<BackendlessCollection<Main>>( this, getString( R.string.loading_mains ), true )
    {

        @Override
        public void handleResponse( BackendlessCollection<Main> mainsBackendlessCollection )
        {
            mains = mainsBackendlessCollection;

            addMoreItems( mainsBackendlessCollection );

            super.handleResponse( mainsBackendlessCollection );
        }
    } );

    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById( android.R.id.list );
    list.setOnScrollListener( new AbsListView.OnScrollListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged( AbsListView view, int scrollState )
        {

            }


        @Override
        public void onScroll( AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount )
        {


            if( needToLoadItems( firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount ) )
            { progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
```

progressDialog.setMessage("Loading more data please wait...");
progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false); progressDialog.setCancelable(true);progressDialog.show();

```
                isLoadingItems = true;
                mains.nextPage( new LoadingCallBack<BackendlessCollection<Main>>( MainActivity.this )
                {
                    @Override
                    public void handleResponse( BackendlessCollection<Main> nextPage )
                    {


                            progressDialog.dismiss();


                        mains = nextPage;
                        addMoreItems( nextPage );

                        isLoadingItems = false;
                    }
                } );
            }
        }
    } );
}


private boolean needToLoadItems( int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount )
{

       return !isLoadingItems && totalItemCount != 0 && totalItemCount - (visibleItemCount + firstVisibleItem) < visibleItemCount / 2;
```

}

```
private void addMoreItems( BackendlessCollection<Main> nextPage )
{
    totalMains.addAll( nextPage.getCurrentPage() );
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

I am new at android..

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question? What exactly have you tried and what exactly does not work?

Comment: I am having problem that after the whole list is loaded from backendless then on scroll it is showing progress dialog but there is nothing to load more So I dont know how to stop progress dialog when all the list of data is loaded.

Comment: To stop progress dialog use the dismiss method of progress dialog class. Please make sure, that your dialog is not null before you dismiss it. Use an if statement to verify the same.

Comment: I am Unable to get when the whole data from backendless is loaded and then on scroll changed progress diadog should not be invoked Please help me !!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use ProgressBar instead of ProgressDialog. See my answer here
[Backendless: I can not access retrieved data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35993055/backendless-i-can-not-access-retrieved-data/36045867#36045867)